# NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory using BigDecimal .to_s method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, out-of-memory, bigdecimal

I use **Ruby 2.2.3** and **Rails 4.2.3**. I get an `NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory` using the following code in *irb* console:

```
# Using 123e+1000000000000000000
BigDecimal('123e+1000000000000000000').to_s
#=> NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory
```

But this example with a more bigger number works:

```
# Using 123e+1000000000000000000000000000000000
BigDecimal('123e+1000000000000000000000000000000000').to_s
#=> "Infinity"
```

Here the code of `BigDecimal`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/big_decimal/conversions.rb

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you run out of memory is nothing strange. The number `123e+1000000000000000000` has a quintillion zeroes. Representing it as a string would take a quintillion characters.

At one byte per character, you're looking at (roughly) `10^18` bytes, `10^15` kilobytes, `10^12` megabytes, or `10^9` gigabytes. So unless you have in the range of a billion gigabytes of RAM, it's not going to work that well.

Once the number passed to the `BigDecimal` constructor passes the biggest number that can be represented on your system, it will overflow to the constant `BigDecimal::INFINITY`, which when converted to a string, is just `Infinity`, and can clearly fit in memory:

```
BigDecimal('123e+1000000000000000000000000000000000') == BigDecimal::INFINITY
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert it to a float? This works for me:

```
BigDecimal('123e+1000000000000000000').to_f
=> Infinity
```

Comment: @phlegx what do you mean by "should work"? If your computer doesn't have enough memory to allocate for that string then well... maybe good it's not trying